# TMT Steel in layers

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, reinforced-concrete

The Site Engineer and I were arguing about the placement of the reinforcement bars in layers. The Steel technician (TMT) placed the third layer of reinforcement in the 2nd layer. I said it didn't matter in terms of steel area, but the Client said it must be in the proper layer. What is the reason behind the multiple layers of TMT steel bars?
Edit 1
For Better Clarity, I made this.

[image]

Edit 2
I am not joking drawing is like this.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: How have you analysed the performance of the various configurations? Perhaps the answer is "The customer gets what they want and pay for".

Comment: What is "TMT" steel?

Comment: @r13 A brief google search on TMT rebar yielded a few results.  Apparently its a type of rebar and stands for Thermo mechanically treated rebar.  Here is [one of the links](https://steeloncall.com/what-is-the-difference-between-tmt-and-twisted-rebars).  To me it standard reinforcing steel in my neck of the woods at this day an age.

Comment: Is this for a slab or for a beam?  What kind of thickness and spacing between the layers are we looking at?

Comment: @ForwardEd 32 Dia with the spacing of 220c/c but since the 3rd layer bar is in 2nd Layer the net spacing becomes 110c/c.. It is for Lift Pit. Depth is 2100mm.

Comment: Note that I've rewritten my answer after seeing the differing layouts, since they completely changed the issues at hand. My conclusion without the drawings was easy-going, saying the technician was correct in his actions but that it also wasn't a big deal. Having seen the drawings, however, I can now say the technician was absolutely correct and the design layout is very questionable.

Comment: I am assuming this is for the floor slave of the lift pit.  How thick is the slab?  Can you update your sketch to show slab thickness and where all 3 layers are?

Comment: Where are the transverse bars?  how big is this pit?  32 dia. rebar seems quite beefy.  I would suspect there are some pretty significant loads being dealt with.

Comment: @ForwardEd's questions are indeed really relevant. Would it be possible for you to [edit] your question, adding the actual schematics for this beam/slab, or at least a full to-scale sketch of what's going on? I'd so far been assuming this was the positive reinforcement on a beam, but Ed's questions have made me realize this is entirely unclear.

Comment: @Wasabi Given the spacing of 110 and 220,  that would be some beam!  Though not unheard of for things like box girders and culverts.  I highly suspect this is for a floor slab or wall, but I am not sure which.

Comment: I am reminded of the case in my professional engineering organization where the field engineer basically directed the contractor to shift the rebar left and right avoid the piles coming through the slab.  The field engineering was found at fault as the shifting of the rebar caused the slab to behave in a way the designer had not intended.  The shifting of the rebar caused the slab to be over reinforced in some portions and under reinforced in others.  The hearing said the correct course of action would have been to send the problem back to the design engineer for a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Just to clarify: you're talking about the reinforcement for the thick portion of the slab, which has ϕ25@220 for the positive reinforcement and ϕ16@250+ϕ12@250 (for an average spacing of 125, not 110)? If so, my answer is going to change completely again and the technician will have made a disastrous mistake.

Comment: @ForwardEd: Yeah, I mostly worked with bridges and designed a fair number of box girders, so the values weren't too shocking. Though, to be honest, I hadn't realized how big the spacing was.

Answer (score 0):

"**What is the reason behind the multiple layers of TMT steel bars?**"

The only reason I can think of, for placing steel in multi layers, is "to maintain proper spacing between reinforcing bars and to avoid congestion at a layer to facilitate concrete placement and vibration."

**Why does the position of layers matters?**

As shown below, the centroid position changes for the two cases. Since the effective lever arm for the bending moment is "$d  = h - d_c$", for your case, the actual "$d$" is less than the "$d$" used in design, which would result in lower moment capacity.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ACI 318-11 section 7.6.6 allows and defines the details of bundled rebars.

It allows for bundles of 2 or 3 or 4 bars to a maximum size of #11.

> ACI-318-11-Clause 7.6.6.1 to 7.6.6.5 has specified some restrictions. 7.6.6 — Bundled bars7.6.6.1   —   Groups   of   parallel   reinforcing   barsbundled  in  contact  to  act  as  a  unit  shall  be  limited  tofour in any one bundle.7.6.6.2  —  Bundled  bars  shall  be  enclosed  withinstirrups or ties.7.6.6.3 —  Bars  larger  than  No.  11  shall  not  bebundled in beams.R7.6.6 — Bundled barsBond  research7.8  showed  that  bar  cutoffs  within  bundlesshould be staggered. Bundled bars should be tied, wired, orotherwise fastened together to ensure remaining in positionwhether vertical or horizontal.A  limitation  that  bars  larger  than  No.  11  not  be  bundled  inbeams or girders is a practical limit for application to buildingsize members. (The “Standard Specifications for HighwayBridges”7.9  permits  two-bar  bundles  for  No.  14  and  No.  18bars  in  bridge  girders.)  Conformance  to  the  crack  controlrequirements  of  10.6  will  effectively  preclude  bundling  of

'

[image: bundled bars perimeter]

Answer (score 0):

Even after the update with the design plans and section, I am still a bit confused by your layer nomenclature or number system.  Further more looking at the rebar layout drawing, it is using a naming system I am not familiar with.  The first two sets of drawings look like shop drawings, where as the bottom section looks like its from a design drawing.  Based on what I could interpret, your layout should look something like the following.

[image]

I am not familiar with your rebar detailing requirements so cover, bend radius, and hooks are probably way off the mark.

```
Yellow    - 12T Bar
Red       - 16T Bar
Cyan/Blue - 20T Bar
Green     - 25T Bar
```

Unlike your design drawings, the bars in the sketch above are spaced according to the design.  It felt like the bars in the section were all equally spaced.

I left the bars for the pit walls out.

Unfortunately I am not sure which bars make up layer 2 and layer 3.

I for slabs I am used to using either:

```
 TUL - Top Upper Layer
 TLL - Top Lower Layer
 BUL - Bottom Upper Layer
 BLL - Bottom Lower Layer
```

or

```
 TL - Top Longitudinal
 TT - Top Transverse
 BL - Bottom Longitudinal
 BT - Bottom Transverse
 (problem with this is you need to know the orientation)
```

or in the case of beam/girder

```
 Layer 1  Closest to extreme tension (bottom normally)
 Layer 2
 Layer 3
 ...
 Layer n-1
 Layer n  Closest to extreme compression
```

Big girders (especially bridges) tend to have a lot layers.  You don't always know how many, but you know for sure there will be at least one and it will always be in the bottom.  Hence why counting from the bottom makes sense.  Most girders will not rely on compression steel.  If there is some its usually for help hold the stirrups.  A lot of engineers will ignore compression reinforcing when doing their capacity check unless they really need it.